# Using templates to check for fields in a struct, enable a function if, and give a nice error message if that fails?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I've got A C++ class that defines an interface for data serialization to JSON:

```
 class JsonSerializable
 {
 public:
      QJsonDocument toJSON() const;
      void fromJSON(QJsonDocument const& json);

 protected:
     virtual QJsonDocument serialize() const = 0;
     virtual oid deserialize(QJsonDocument const& json) = 0;
 };
```

The idea of `toJSON()` vs. `serialize()` and their counterpart is that the protected methods a class needs to implement only need to concern themselves with actually handling the data, whereas the public methods perform basic checks for validity.

Now I'd like to introduce JSON schema for finer-grained checks. I want to enable the JSON schema part only if a schema exists. Thus, I began introducing a `struct` like so:

```
 template <class Serializable>
 struct JsonSchema {};

 template <>
 struct JsonSchema<MySerializingClass>
 {
      static const char schemaURI[] = "...";
 };
```

I've not finished the approach because I am unsure how to realize the following:

1. The schema-checking code in `fromJSON()` should only be compiled if a template specialization of the `JsonSchema` struct exists.
2. If this struct exist, I'd like the compiler to check if a `schemaURI` field exists and whether its size is >0. If not, I'd like to give the programmer a descriptive error message like I can do with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.

Is that possible? The API is not finalized; the most important part here is that the checks should happen at compile time. The `schemaURI` parameter is set by the programmer, and does not change at runtime --- the schema file is part of the distributed program and administered via a resource system, so it is guaranteed to be available if the program compiles.

Comment: One part of this is probably _not_ possible (checking that the size is >0). It _might_ be possible if you require a `const char[]` instead of a `const char*`.

Comment: `const char[]` would be more sensible anyways, sorry for the mistake. Everything should happen at compile time, so `static const char[]` is probably even better... I'll adjust my question. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call it a mistake - `const char*` is the normal thing to use when assigning a string literal, after all, and it's not wrong. Using `const char[]` though means the compiler _should_ know how long it is - I believe there may be something in `<type_traits>` to get the length of an array type.

Comment: By the way, you'd declare it like this: `static const char schemaURI[] = "...";`

Comment: Thanks! The length check is a nice-to-have I wager I'll get if the rest works... Any ideas on the template magic?

Comment: I've been giving it some thought, but I think you might have to rethink your methods quite a bit. Some static polymorphism (ie CRTP) might help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is impossible with your current design. For example, it is impossible with your example code for `fromJSON` to statically know the type of the class it has been invoked on. Since you want compile-type checking, I think you might have to use static polymorphism, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct JsonSchema {};

template<typename Derived, typename SchemaCheck = void>
class JsonSerializable {
public:
    QJsonDocument toJSON() const;
    void fromJSON(QJsonDocument const& json);
};

template<typename Derived, typename SchemaCheck>
QJsonDocument JsonSerializable<Derived,SchemaCheck>::toJSON() const {
    // do whatever you need to do here, and call serialize() like this:
    static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->serialize();
}

template<typename Derived, typename SchemaCheck>
void JsonSerializable<Derived,SchemaCheck>::fromJSON(QJsonDocument const& json) {
    // do whatever you need to do when there's no schema, and call deserialize() like this:
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->deserialize(json);
}

template<typename Derived>
class JsonSerializable<Derived,
    // We check extent > 1 instead of extent > 0 because a string constant of length 0 requires an array of length 1 to hold it.
    // If schemaURI doesn't exist at all, this will also fail and cause the default version (above) to be used.
    std::enable_if<(std::extent<decltype(JsonSchema<Derived>::schemaURI)>::value > 1), Derived>> {
public:
    // It's probably easier to define these inline. It might get pretty complicated otherwise.
    QJsonDocument toJSON() const {
        // Pretty much the same as before, unless you need some different behaviour when there's a schema
        static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->serialize();
    }
    void fromJSON(QJsonDocument const& json) {
        // There's a schema now, so act accordingly.
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->deserialize(json);
    }
};
```

Then you declare a serializable class like this:

```
class MySerializingClass : public JsonSerializable<MySerializingClass> {
public:
    QJsonDocument serialize() const;
    void deserialize(QJsonDocument const& json);
};
```

If you need to be able to pass around `JsonSerializable` objects without knowing what they are, you can do that by introducing an additional base class:

```
class JsonSerializableBase {
public:
    virtual QJsonDocument toJSON() const = 0;
    virtual void fromJSON(QJsonDocument const& json) = 0;
};
```

Then change the `JsonSerializable` declarations to inherit from it:

```
template<typename Derived, typename SchemaCheck = void>
class JsonSerializable : public JsonSerializableBase
```

For the schema case, it would look like this:

```
template<typename Derived>
class JsonSerializable<Derived,
    // We check extent > 1 instead of extent > 0 because a string constant of length 0 requires an array of length 1 to hold it.
    std::enable_if<(std::extent<decltype(JsonSchema<Derived>::schemaURI)>::value > 1), Derived>> : public JsonSerializableBase
```

I tested that this code compiles with the following `main()`:

```
using QJsonDocument = std::string; // Since I don't have Qt handy
int main(int,char*[]) {
    MySerializingClass foo;
    foo.toJSON();
    foo.fromJSON("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully it does what you want.

Comment: Yep, that certainly shows me how to do it. Since my API is not finished yet, I can implement this quite easily. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is wondering how to do this if static polymorphism is not an option, for example, when Qt's moc interferes: A free function can help then. Here's the code:

```
class JsonSerializable
{
public:
    virtual QJsonDocument toJSON() const = 0;
    virtual void fromJSON(const QJsonDocument &json) = 0;
};


template <class C>
struct JsonSchema
{
    static constexpr char const schemaURI[] = "";
};


template <
    class C,
    typename std::enable_if<(std::is_base_of<JsonSerializable, C>
            ::value
        && std::extent<decltype(JsonSchema<C>::schemaURI)>
             ::value <= 1),
        int>::type = 0>
void deserialize(C& serializable, QJsonDocument const& json)
{
    serializable.fromJSON(json);
}


template <
    class C,
    typename std::enable_if<(std::is_base_of<JsonSerializable, C>
            ::value
        && std::extent<decltype(JsonSchema<C>::schemaURI)>
             ::value > 1),
        int>::type = 0>
void deserialize(C& serializable, QJsonDocument const& json)
{
    /* Do the schema checking here: */

    checkSchema(json, JsonSerializable<C>::schemaURI);
    serializable.fromJSON(json);
}
```